# Illegal Path name when creating MessageQueue

Tags: c, msmq

Hello I am new in MSMQ,

having some C++ components I want to connect them via Microsoft Message Queue.
Using the function from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms711416(v=vs.85).aspx. I want to create a new Message Queue.

This function I call with:

```
SECURITY_DESCRIPTOR securityDescriptor;
CreateSecurityDescriptor(&securityDescriptor);
WCHAR wszOutFormatName[256];
DWORD dwOutFormatNameLength;

CreateMSMQQueue(L"DIRECT=OS:.\\PRIVATE$\\MyQueue", &securityDescriptor, wszOutFormatName, &dwOutFormatNameLength);
```

`CreateSecurityDescriptor` creates as the name says a Default SecurityDescriptor. I can post the code if needed.

But the creating fails with the error code `MQ_ERROR_ILLEGAL_QUEUE_PATHNAME`. Which means:

> PROPID_Q_PATHNAME contains an illegal Message Queuing path name string.

What is wrong with `L"DIRECT=OS:.\\PRIVATE$\\MyQueue"` ?
I got from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700996(v=vs.85).aspx

I am grateful for any help.

Comment: Just a guess, but the example from msdn is just like yours except it has one backslash where you have a pair of them. So try L"DIRECT=OS:.\PRIVATE$\MyQueue"

Comment: @Marichyasana I tried this too. But I got the same error message.

Answer (score 0):

You can only reference an existing queue with a format name.
You cannot create a new queue with one.
Use a path name instead.

[Difference between Path name and Format name when accessing MSMQ queues](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/johnbreakwell/2009/02/26/difference-between-path-name-and-format-name-when-accessing-msmq-queues/)